# Way to influence the order returned by ApplicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()?

Tags: spring

I am trying to invoke an operation of a set of beans by retrieving them from `appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()`.The order of invoking the operation matters to me as one bean's operation is dependent on other.

I have tried the following to set this order.

```
1.PriorityOrdered interface
2.@DependsOn annotation
3.BeansPostProcessor interface
```

But none of them seem to influence the order in the list. By default it is returning the beans in the order in which they are encountered in classpath.

Two questions.

1.What does it mean when the above approaches set the order of initialization to the bean?

2.Can the order of retrieval of bean names using appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames() be influenced in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand from your question what is really your problem. Do you want to alter the order of initializing beans or to get the names of beans in the order they have been defined in your configurations?

***1.What does it mean when the above approaches set the order of initialization to the bean?***

`ApplicationContext` is responsible for instantiating, configuring and wiring your application's beans. `ApplicationContext` in an early step of it's life cycle reads your configurations (XML, Annotations, Java code configurations, etc) and instantiates those beans. When we are talking about the order of initializing beans, we mean which bean will be instantiated by the `ApplicationContext` sooner and which will be instantiated later. For example if you have two classes `A` and `B` in which `B` depends on `A` like below:

```
class A {
}

class B {

   private A a;

   public B(A a) {
      this.a = a;
   }

}
```

As you can see in order to instantiate `B` we need an instance of `A`.

**DependsOn**

Beans on which the current bean depends. Any beans specified are guaranteed to be created by the container before this bean. ([DependsOn Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html))

**BeanPostProcessor**

A `BeanPostProcessor` allows you to modify a been after it is instantiated by the container. I don't think you can achieve what you want with a bean post processor. [Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp)

**PriorityOrdered**

[PriorityOrdered](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/PriorityOrdered.html) is an extension of [Ordered](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html) interface. From the documentation:

> Ordered is an interface that can be implemented by objects that should
>   be orderable, for example in a Collection. The actual order can be
>   interpreted as prioritization, with the first object (with the lowest
>   order value) having the highest priority.
>
> Note that there is also a priority marker for this interface:
>   PriorityOrdered. Order values expressed by PriorityOrdered objects
>   always apply before same order values expressed by plain Ordered
>   objects.

From the documentation of `PriorityOrdered`

> Extension of the `Ordered` interface, expressing a priority ordering:
>   order values expressed by `PriorityOrdered` objects always apply before
>   same order values expressed by plain Ordered objects. This is
>   primarily a special-purpose interface, used for objects where it is
>   particularly important to recognize prioritized objects first, without
>   even obtaining the remaining objects. A typical example: prioritized
>   post-processors in a Spring `ApplicationContext`.

Also I don't think you can achieve what you want from this interface too.

***2.Can the order of retrieval of bean names using appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames() be influenced in any way?***

The `getBeanDefinitionNames()` method only returns an array of strings containing the names of all the beans defined in the current factory ([Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeanDefinitionNames--)).